# Percentage Math Total

Tags: percentages

Let's assume a city has 104 barrels of oil which is 7% of the country's entire oil. How can I calculate the total oil that the country has?

Answer (score 0):

If 104 is 7% of the total oil, then $$\frac{7x}{100} = 104$$ Where x represents the total quantity of oil.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$0.07\cdot T= 104$, so $T=\ ?$